# Entity Framework Code First: Many to many self referencing, naming convention

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, naming-conventions, code-first

**Working example**

```
class Product
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Color
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

class ProductColor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ColorId")]
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
}
```

After adding and applying migrations, when I add to Product list of ProductColors entity context will not be changed ( no need to add and apply new migration )

```
class Product
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ProductColor> ProductColors { get; set; }
}
```

This is ok.

**Not working example**

But how name list inside the Product, if need to reference Products to Products ? For example

```
class ProductForm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FormId")]
    public Product Form { get; set; }
    public int FormId { get; set; }

    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add list

```
class Product 
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ProductForm> ProductForms { get;set;}
}
```

This will change entity context. This is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your use of convention names is fine, but you are doing some strange things with e.g. in class ProductColor having property ProductId and Product - just stick to one of them, this then keeps repeating later in your code.  It looks you also have some errors in your code like public Product Form, should be likely public Form Form

Comment: @Turo When he wants to use foreign key association he has no other choice than including both the `Product` and `ProductId`. Furthermore I don't think the question is really clear. "But how name list inside the Product, if need to reference Products to Products ?" this sentence doesn't make sense. And after that you start using `ProductForm` and `ProductType` out of nowhere, you want to add that to `Products` too or something?

Comment: `ProductType` doesn't mean anything, i just copy it from my code. Important is the Form and Product, both of items is type of `Product`, I just call second of them Form.

Comment: Like a `ProductColor`, I need list with `ProductForms`. 
In the `Product` class for Product colors true name is ''ProductColors", it's default name convention from Entity. But i don't know how to name ProductForms, because they are relationship of `Product` and `Product` ( many to many )